# How to list all the roles existing in informix database?

Tags: informix

I know in *sysusers* table, we can see roles associated with each user in *defrole* column.

Now I have been searching in below tables:

*B_APP_ROLES*

*ROLES*

But I can't find roles defined in *defrole* column in above tables.

Also can we see which tables have granted what roles?

Comment: There is no description in the Informix documentation for system catalog tables with the names `B_APP_ROLES` and `ROLES`. So they are probably tables created by an application and you should refer to that application documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dbschema -r all -d database_name should list all the roles created and grants to those roles for that particular database.

This information I believe would be coming from the sysroleauth table.

Then if you want to see what table level permissions a particular role has, the role name would be the grantee column in systabauth.

So the query would be like

select * from systabauth where grantee = "rolename";